# Web API Help page with cross authentication identity from other site

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, web-config, asp.net-web-api-helppages

**SCENARIO**

I've a site in IIS with two applications.

The principal `("A")` is a REST service made with Web API 2 in C#, that contains inside an Areas folder with an autogenerated Help Page `("B")`.
`"A"` uses a header authorization, not with forms authentications. At this moment `"B"` doesn't have any security.

The second application is a C# MVC site  `("C")` with Authentication Forms and a login. It has a link to the documentation `("B")`.

**GOAL**

The main idea is login into `"C"`, click on the link provided and get access into `"B"`. The thing here is this one: If you try to enter directly on the URL of `"B"` without login into `"C"`, you get a redirect to `"C"`

**ACTUAL SITUATION**

So what I did, first of all, is in `"B"`, file `HelpController.cs`:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

    if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
       *** do things
```

At first, this works for localhost because is the same site in my PC. So I deployed at DEV but of course, it didn't work.

So I was work with these links:

[Forms Authentication Across Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc(v=vs.100).aspx)
[How To: Configure MachineKey in ASP.NET 2.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998288.aspx)
[machineKey Element (ASP.NET Settings Schema)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/w8h3skw9(v=vs.100).aspx)
[MachineKeySection.CompatibilityMode Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.machinekeysection.compatibilitymode.aspx)

After a lot of work and crypto errors, it could only work with a 32 len key. Other configurations didn't work. The code to generate this key was:

.NET Fiddler: [Generate Encrypted MachineKey](https://dotnetfiddle.net/f475qi)

```
int len = 64;
byte[] buff = new byte[len/2];
RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new 
RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
rng.GetBytes(buff);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len);
for (int i=0; i<buff.Length; i++)
  sb.Append(string.Format("{0:X2}", buff[i]));
Console.WriteLine(sb);
```

So I put this configuration on "C" and it works!

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Logon" cookieless="UseCookies" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="480" 
  name="ASPXFORMSAUTH" 
    protection="All"  
    path="/" 
  />
</authentication>


 <machineKey
  validationKey="5FEA041C5EE0836460BC2C3D8636F2610A357D9B7D606591112089CDEBDA871D" 
  decryptionKey="C8E79DC95283007C6E3D6E6698130501680CE032C28DDE4DDB678BAB683C2AFA" 
 />
```

but then, in the `"C"` web.config located at Areas\HelpPage\Views this code:

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms cookieless="UseCookies" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="480" 
  name="ASPXFORMSAUTH" 
    protection="All"  
    path="/" 
  />

     <machineKey
  validationKey="5FEA041C5EE0836460BC2C3D8636F2610A357D9B7D606591112089CDEBDA871D" 
  decryptionKey="C8E79DC95283007C6E3D6E6698130501680CE032C28DDE4DDB678BAB683C2AFA" 
 />
```

but didn't work. I mean, the "A" and "B" sites works, but `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is always false

I think I'm missing or mixing something. I'm lost at this point. When I put the configuration in the "A" web config, everything explodes with a 500 because I don't have authentication form in the REST service.

Any tip, comment, answer or question will be preciated, meanwhile I still fight with this. Thanks in advance!

---

**UPDATE 1**

Debugging the code, I get these values:

```
FormsAuthentication.CookiesSupported == true
```

but

```
Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] == null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration must be done on the web config of the web api, not the config of the help area.